# Must I always use `url` field in making outbound calls with Twilio API in Python?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I've been trying to figure out how to make outbound call to leave a voicemail when answering machine is detected. I'm still in the beginning of the exploration and been trying to follow Twilio example like [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/quickstart/python). I want to use Python, so I'm copy-pasting the example from Twilio below:

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import Client


# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
# DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = 'your account sid'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
                        url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
                        to='+1555123456',
                        from_='+1501123456'
                    )

print(call.sid)
```

In the above code, it seems like Twilio's Python SDK always expects `url` (publicly available XML file/response) as resource to ping to. I'm wondering if I can build a valid XML (TwiML) file and refer to it in the above `client.calls.create(...)` call. In other words, how do I make Twilio 'speak' what I designed in my **local (on my computer) XML file** (if that's even possible)? I only plan to run my Python script from my personal computer on need basis, and I don't have any access to server anywhere.

Thank you in advance for your answer/suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A publicly accessible URL is a requirement. You can use [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio) or [Twilio Serverless Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) if you want Twilio to host your logic so you don't need to expose a public URL.

For development, you can use a tool called [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), which will tunnel the Twilio TwiML request to your private application.

You can find more detail here.

[How to test webhooks locally with ngrok - Twilio Tip #6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1uExj7mMgM)

Comment: Thank you so much! This definitely helps and I'm going to try out the options you've shared. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could test this about by using pythons simple http server. and just have it server that file.

```
curl http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml -o voice.xml
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 
#run to above commands then
#try using bellow?
call = client.calls.create(
                    url='http://localhost:8000/voice.xml',
                    to='+1555123456',
                    from_='+1501123456'
                )
#the file at that location is dead simple
<Response>
<Say voice="alice">Thanks for trying our documentation. Enjoy!</Say>
<Play>http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

Comment: Than you for the suggestion. I actually tried using Flask to serve the aforementioned XML file; I just tried the way you suggested using simple http server as well. Both got `Invalid URL format (An attempt to retrieve content from http://0.0.0.0:8000/voice.xml returned the HTTP status code 502)` error. So I'm starting to think that publicly accessible URL is a MUST to use this API.

Comment: Hmm unfortunate they did not allow this option. You could see if putting it on port 80 and putting 0.0.0.0 testserverrandomname127.com entry in your \etc\hosts file and see if that fixes the url format error. Then changing localhost:8000 to http://testserverrandomname127.com